# Rotate a button (or the text inside) in code

Tags: android, button, rotation

I have to rotate a button (or the text inside, it's the same) by random degree by coding. Is there any button.setRotate(x) in API level lower then 11??

Comment: what's wrong with this question?

Comment: It shows no research effort. Open the `Button` class doc, use the search function of your browser and type `rotation` in the search field and you'll see what I mean.

Comment: I have searched a lot, but most of questions are about rotating images by pressing button..not rotate the button itself.
in the documentation, I found only "setRotation(float) = rotation of the VIEW, in degree"..

I don't know how to implement to rotate the button. button.setRotate(x) doesn't work.

Comment: Well, as said your question **doesn't show** that you did any research, not that you actually didn't search at all.  Note that a Button is a View (extends the View class). Try button.setRotation(x) instead and see where you go from there.

Comment: edit: I have mixed setRotate with setRotation. However button.setRotation(x) doesn't work.
Eclipse says "The method setRotation(float) is undefined for the type Button"

Comment: Oh sorry, my bad actually. Just saw that setRotation() is available since API level 11 (Android 3.0). If you target a lower version, you can't use this. Actually in this case it's a bit tricky. I'll see if I can figure this one out.

Comment: I see. hoping in any alternative..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, had a look and the answer is: It's complicated.

You can rotate the button using the old animation framework, e.g. like this:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

// rotation from 0 to 90 degrees here
RotateAnimation a = new RotateAnimation(0, 90);
a.setFillAfter(true);
a.setDuration(0);
button.startAnimation(a);
```

The problem here is that the button looks rotated, but can't be clicked correctly. The coordinates that trigger the click event are the ones at the area the button had before beeing rotated.

Since this is not a very good solution, your best bet is probably to write a custom view that extends the Button class and rotate the buttons canvas in `onDraw()`. You also have to override `onMeasure()` in this case. See [Custom Components](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) for a introduction what to do.

Apart from that you can try to intercept click events from the buttons parent layout and trigger the appropriate event when the click happened within the buttons current coordinates. This is somewhat "hacky" though.

Comment: tomorrow I'll get a try! my buttons are square, so it could work.

Comment: adding the pivot information to center the animation, it's perfect!! Thank you

RotateAnimation a = new RotateAnimation(0, 90,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f,Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);

Comment: please im new to android devlopment, could you show me how to extend the button class, with its rotation code ?

Comment: this is not working for me... I have buttons with a drawable for each state. Could this be the problem?