# Is it possible to define different rotations in one xml file?

Tags: android, xml, rotation

I would like to know if it is possible to have two different type of rotations in Android in the xml file for example:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"></rotate>
    <rotate2
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="180"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
       android:duration="0" ></rotate2>

</set>
```

the first rotate i use it to rotate an imageView:

```
 final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.rotate);
```

And i want to use the second rotate (rotate2) to rotate a text within an ImageButton is this possible or no ?

when i try to get the rotate2 in my java class i get an error so my question is if the only way i have to fix this is to create rotate2 in an other xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get the error because `<rotate2>` is not a valid child element of the `<set>` element. The valid elements are either an `<alpha>`, `<scale>`, `<translate>`, `<rotate>`, or `<set>` element that holds a group (or groups) of other animation elements (even nested `<set>` elements) [[1]](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/animation-resource.html#View).

The following should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="180"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="0" />

</set>
```

**EDIT**

If you want to animate different views with different animations, you need to specify separate animation resource files and loading them separately for each view that needs to be animated.

*rotate1.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:duration="2000"
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="360"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"/>
</set>
```

*rotate2.xml:*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <rotate
        android:fromDegrees="0"
        android:toDegrees="180"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:duration="0" />
</set>
```

In Java code, you should have something like what I have below. `rotate2` would animate the `imageButton` and not it's content.

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
Animation rotate1 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.rotate1);
imageView.startAnimation(rotate1);

ImageButton imageButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButton);
Animation rotate2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(), R.anim.rotate2);
imageButton.startAnimation(rotate2);
```

In order to rotate the text inside the `ImageButton`, I would suggest writing a custom view that extends the `ImageButton` class and rotating the `ImageButton`'s canvas in `onDraw()`. You also have to override `onMeasure()` [[2]](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8591478/2688283). For a more detailed guide on creating a custom view, refer to the [Android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html).

Comment: so it is not possible to define more than 1 rotation in the same xml file right  ?

Comment: It is possible. I edited your code in my answer. Did you see if it works?

Comment: ok, and to distinguish between the two rotate i only have to add an id for each one right  ?

Comment: No, it's not possible to set an id on the rotate element. Why do you need to distinguish between the two? What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: the first rotate which duration = 2000 i am using on imageView as you can see here : `final ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        final Animation an = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getBaseContext(),R.anim.rotate);` 
the second one i want tu use it for textView how can i retrieve each one from my classes ??

Comment: Please update your question with your code. I suggest having separate animation resource files and loading them separately for each view that needs to be animated; but I can't say much without seeing your code.

Comment: ok, i edited my question, this is what i thought too a separate animarion res file.